# Scala map companion

Tags: scala

Essentially what I want to do is create an Object that has the traits of a Codec, and the companion class that has the traits of a Message, and I want to put the object in a map, so I can use it to decode messages when only given an opcode.

Also, there will be many different Codecs because each Message has a unique signature.

Edit-
I have a trait called Codec, and a trait called Message.

What types would I specify for the map?

Comment: This is a statement of what you want to do, but where's the question?  You also completely failed to mention any context for what you actually mean by "Message" and "Codec", this could be telephony, email cryptography, anything really.

Comment: The question is, how would I go about doing that. Specifically, what types would be specified for the map. Also, the context isn't relevant, seeing that's not what I'm having issues with.

Comment: [Put down the chocolate-covered banana and step away from the European currency systems](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html)

Comment: I didn't vote to close two days ago, because it seemed like there might be a decent question lurking here if you would take a bit more time to clarify your requirements.  At this point, though, your best bet is to close this question and open a new question that clearly expresses your goals.

Answer (score 1):

If opcodes are `String`s and codecs are of type `Codec`, then you presumably want a `Map[String,Codec]`

But... You clearly define `Codec` to be a singleton `object`, even going so far as to state that it would have a companion class.  So this would be a fairly useless map as all the values would be identical.  It also means you couldn't have multiple codecs, as per your second paragraph.